# How to give a two dimensional array an initial value in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm working on an SPI module that involves one master and three slaves. In the test bench, I'd like to give each of the slaves a parallel load through a multidimensional array that's an input to the SPI module

```
reg [7:0] slaves_inload [3:1]= ?
```

I have no idea what should I write on the RHS of this. Suppose I'd like to pass : `8'b11101101`, `8'b10101010` and `8'b10001000` for slaves [1], [2], [3], respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to initialize the array is as follows:

```
reg [7:0] slaves_inload [3:1] = '{8'b10001000, 8'b10101010, 8'b11101101};
                                 //    3            2            1
```

This syntax can be seen in the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 10.9.1 *Array assignment patterns*.